# Pinging your computers symbolic name

Tags: networking

I have been playing about with pinging website and getting their IP addresses while seeing how quickly a packet be sent and back, now i tried to ping my own PC and instead of getting the ip address format of 193.22.33.201 etc im now getting fe80::18od etc etc why would this be happening?

Comment: looks like an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6 address to me

Answer (score 3):

That's your [link-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices) [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -4 command line parameter to force the ping command to use IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your system has used an IPv6 resolution of the name instead of an IPv4 resolution; in general, names map to more than one address and it is up to negotiation (typically done automatically for you by system functions like `getaddrinfo`) to sort out which to actually use. For purely local communications (whether with `localhost` or your public hostname) it doesn't really matter which communication protocol is used, since the data never leaves the machine anyway.